# Changing views (div) with toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I the index.html I want to toggle with the `#btn` between two different views:

- NON-REALTIME: `#getDateTime` and `#showData` shall be visible
- REALTIME: `#stateBela` shall be visible

**Question:** It works, but what isn't working as follows:

- ALL (!) divs are visible after starting the index.html, but only the
  `#stateBela` should be visible, because the default setting is "REALTIME". How can I do that?

The function toggleState is written in the upper "**head**-part"...

```
<head>
     <!-- define the toggle function -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleState(item){

           if(item.className == "on") {
              item.className="off";
              item.value="NON-REALTIME";

              document.getElementById("stateBela").style.display = 'none';

              document.getElementById("getDateTime").style.display = 'inline';
              document.getElementById("showData").style.display = 'inline';

           } else {
              item.className="on";
              item.value="REALTIME";

              document.getElementById("stateBela").style.display = 'inline';

              document.getElementById("getDateTime").style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById("showData").style.display = 'none';
           }
        }
     </script>
</head>
```

...and the divs are written/listed in the lower "**body**-part" of the html code...

```
<body>
    <!-- call function 'toggleState' whenever clicked -->
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="REALTIME" class="on" onclick="toggleState(this)" />


    <div id="stateBela">
        <label>BELA is: offline or online</label>
    </div>

    <div id="getDateTime">
        <label>After:</label><input id="afterDate" name="afterDate" type="text" value="Date">
        <label>To:</label><input id="toDate" name="afterDate" type="text" value="Date" />
        <label>After:</label><input id="afterTime" name="afterTime" type="text" value="Time" />
        <label>To:</label><input id="toTime" name="toTime" type="text" value="Time" />
    </div>

    <div id="showData">
        <button>Show data</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#getDateTime, #showData {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It would have been so easy :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a style attribute to hide them on page load.

```
<div id="getDateTime" style="display:none">
    <label>After:</label><input id="afterDate" name="afterDate" type="text" value="Date">
    <label>To:</label><input id="toDate" name="afterDate" type="text" value="Date" />
    <label>After:</label><input id="afterTime" name="afterTime" type="text" value="Time" />
    <label>To:</label><input id="toTime" name="toTime" type="text" value="Time" />
</div>

<div id="showData" style="display:none">
    <button>Show data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It would have been so easy :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add these lines in your javascript :

```
function startState {
    toggleState(document.getElementById("btn"));
}

window.onload = startState;
```